# Regular expressions: Matching text up to last index of character

Tags: regex, http

For example:

> http://foobar.com/foo/bar/foobar.php

From this address, I need to extract the following:

> http://foobar.com/foo/bar

I have tried with the following regex:

```
(?<namespace>.*)/.*?
```

but returned value is

> http:

Can anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Are you using a particular development environment or framework?  Many languages have functions that are specifically designed to parse a URL and return its components.  That would probably be a better approach then regex, if it's an option for you.

Comment: Based on the named group syntax plus the .php extension, I'd say they are using PHP (and PCRE 7+ regex), and so is probably better using [strrpos](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strrpos.php) and [substr](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) (or possibly another function, if PHP has a "remove last element" type thing).

Comment: @Jacob Although Bart's solution is working, your comment was the most helpful answer. I am developing in .NET and I am not sure why I decided to go with regular expressions when there are so many already written components that can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
^(?<namespace>.*)/[^/]+$
```

A quick explanation:

```
^                    # the start of input
(?<namespace>.*)/    # zero or more chars followed by a '/' (which the last '/') 
[^/]+                # one or more chars other than '/'
$                    # the end of input
```

Answer (score 2):

I think a regex is overkill here. What programming language are you using? This would be how it's done in JavaScript.

```
var url = 'http://foobar.com/foo/bar/foobar.php'
url.split('/').slice(0,-1).join('/')
```

You could even use **substr** for some performance!

```
var url = 'http://foobar.com/foo/bar/foobar.php'
url.substr(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'))
```

The only reason I offered the array way is because I'm not sure of cross browser compatibility on `lastIndexOf`.

Comment: It's probably PHP, so something like `substr( $url , 0 , strrpos( $url , '/' ) )` would be equivalent to your second one.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this expression:

```
^(?<namespace>.*)/.*$
```